# symbols in math equations

Tags: equations

When I execute the following equation, lambda does not appear in it.  But it works in the text if I use $\lambda$. Any ideas?

```
\begin{equation} \label{Eq:3}
N(t) = N_{0}\times e^{\lambda \times t}
\end{equation}
```

More requested info:

```
 \documentclass[School=School]{Dissertate}
 \parindent 12pt
 \RequirePackage{mathspec}
 \setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Proportional},SizeFeatures= 
 {{Size=-8, OpticalSize=8},{Size= 8-, OpticalSize=12}},]{EB Garamond}
 \setmathrm{EB Garamond}
 \usepackage{mhchem} %superscripts for isotopes
 \usepackage{wasysym} %permille symbol
 \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
 \newfontfamily{\smallcaps}[RawFeature={+c2sc,+scmp}]{EB Garamond}
  \setromanfont[Numbers=OldStyle, Ligatures={Common, TeX}, Scale=1.0]{EB 
  Garamond}
  \setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, BoldFont={Lato Bold}]{Lato Regular}
  \setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Mono}
```

Comment: Same thing happens if I try to do \delta instead of \lambda, there is a blank space in the equation

Comment: Hey, welcome to TeX.sx. Based on what you posted there appears to be no reason for the behavior you describe. If you could post a minimal working example (a compilable code) we might be able to help you.

Comment: As shess says we need more of your doc. My guess: you are loading several font packages that are mutually incompatible. My guess one of them is fourier or mathpazo. Without code, this is only guesswork

Comment: Please tell us if LaTeX issues any particular warning and/or error messages.

Comment: No warning or error messages. I am using a preset template, but I will edit my question to post more info.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't over-use `\times`. For sure, it is *not needed" in `e^{\lambda \times t}`.

Comment: Thanks for adding some of the code. Unfortunately, it is still not possible for us to compile it like that. Please consult this post https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that without a MWE we will not be able to really help you.

Comment: (your preamble seems to heavily modify fonts and and you use a custom-made document class). Your problem is likely to be caused by this, but since we're not able to see what else is in your code or the "Dissertate"-class we will not know what's causing this.

Comment: I agree that the problem might be in the class. If I compile with `article` there is no issue (but I made some reorganization on the declarations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with mathspec, but line 4 in this smaller example is causing the problem.

When removed (as shown- commented out) the lambda appears.

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent 12pt
\RequirePackage{mathspec}
%\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Proportional},SizeFeatures= {{Size=-8, OpticalSize=8},{Size= 8-, OpticalSize=12}},]{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{Eq:3}
N(t) = N_{0}\times e^{\lambda \times t}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```